# A way to see your location history within the command line?

Tags: command-line, directory

Similar to git's `reflog`, I'm looking for a way to see the directories I have moved through. I have lost something and I'm not sure exactly what happened, and something like the reflog is exactly what I need.

Is there any such utility?

Comment: `history | grep cd`?

Comment: It was too simple for me to think of it.

Comment: and perhaps pushd/popd if you use those...